# Parse string with escaped single quotes

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I want to parse a string containing ASCII characters between single quotes and that can contain escaped single quotes by two ' in a row.

> 'string value contained between single quotes -> '' and so on...'

which should result in:

> string value contained between single quotes -> ' and so on...

```
use nom::{
    bytes::complete::{tag, take_while},
    error::{ErrorKind, ParseError},
    sequence::delimited,
    IResult,
};

fn main() {
    let res = string_value::<(&str, ErrorKind)>("'abc''def'");

    assert_eq!(res, Ok(("", "abc\'def")));
}

pub fn is_ascii_char(chr: char) -> bool {
    chr.is_ascii()
}

fn string_value<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    delimited(tag("'"), take_while(is_ascii_char), tag("'"))(i)
}
```

How can I detect escaped quotes and not the end of the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty tricky, but the following works:

```rust
//# nom = "5.0.1"
use nom::{
    bytes::complete::{escaped_transform, tag},
    character::complete::none_of,
    combinator::{recognize, map_parser},
    multi::{many0, separated_list},
    sequence::delimited,
    IResult,
};

fn main() {
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("'abc''def'").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "abc'def");
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("'xy@$%!z'").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "xy@$%!z");
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("'single quotes -> '' and so on...'").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "single quotes -> ' and so on...");
}

fn parse_quoted(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, String> {
    let seq = recognize(separated_list(tag("''"), many0(none_of("'"))));
    let unquote = escaped_transform(none_of("'"), '\'', tag("'"));
    let res = delimited(tag("'"), map_parser(seq, unquote), tag("'"))(input)?;

    Ok(res)
}
```

Some explanations:

1. the parser `seq` recognizes any sequence that alternates between double quotes and anything else;
2. `unquote` transforms any double quotes into single one;
3. `map_parser` then combines the two together to produce the desired result.

Be aware that due to the use of `escaped_transform` combinator, the parsing result is `String` instead of `&str`. I.e., there are extra allocations.

Comment: Thank you! But the allocation is a bit of a deal breaker for me since I will be parsing large amounts of text and want it to be as performant as possible! =)
Isn't it possible to use the `bytes::complete::escaped` parser somehow? This `escaped(alphanumeric1, '\'', char('\''))(i)` does not work... =(

Comment: @mottosson `escaped` and `escaped_transform` have different semantics, the former only check if the input conforms to the given escape rule. Replacing double quotes with single one requires to manipulate the inside of a potentially long string, I don't see how to avoid allocation. Unless you can relax that requirement somehow.

Comment: Hmm... you are correct. Maybe the transform can be made in a separate step in a later stage to circumvent the initial performance implications. So can I use `escaped` then in a similar way as my previous comment to make the parser understand that the string does not end with the first single quote it finds if the next char is also a single quote?

Comment: @mottosson then you can get rid of `unquote` and `map_parser` altogether. `let res = delimited(tag("'"), seq, tag("'"))(input)?;` would be sufficient, and of course the return type is going to be `IResult<&str, &str>`.

Comment: Just another question about `many0`. It says in the docs that many0 `Repeats the embedded parser until it fails and returns the results in a Vec`. Does this mean it will allocate memory even if it's wrapped in `recognize`?

Comment: @mottosson yes, it should. But even so, that'll be `Vec<&str>` and doesn't consume too much memory. Plus, here it is wrapped in `recognize` so the result is never bound to anything or returned, it should be discarded immediately.

Comment: @mottosson that being said, you can experiment with other combintor such as `take_while` here to see if it is even better.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying! =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning nom and below is my trying.

```
let a = r###"'string value contained between single quotes -> '' and so on...'"###;

fn parser(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let len = input.chars().count() - 2;
    delimited(tag("'"), take(len), tag("'"))(input)
}

let (remaining, mut matched) = parser(a).unwrap_or_default();

let sss = matched.replace("''", "'");
matched = &sss;
println!("remaining: {:#?}", remaining);
println!("matched: {:#?}", matched);
```

It prints this result:

```
remaining: ""
matched: "string value contained between single quotes -> ' and so on..."
```

My testing is based on nom 6.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in the real use case where the single quote string is part of a larger input string and doesn't end with '. There are more characters to parse after the last '. This could've been clearer in my question.