# Parsing single-quoted strings with backslash-escaped single quotes with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

This is a variation of [Parsing single-quoted string with escaped quotes with Nom 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904604/parsing-single-quoted-string-with-escaped-quotes-with-nom-5) and [Parse string with escaped single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511515/parse-string-with-escaped-single-quotes). I want to parse strings like `'1 \' 2 \ 3 \\ 4'` (a raw sequence of characters) as `"1 \\' 2 \\ 3 \\\\ 4"` (a Rust string), so I'm not concerned with any escaping other than the possibility of having `\'` inside the strings. Attempts using code from the linked questions:

```rust
use nom::{
  branch::alt,
  bytes::complete::{escaped, tag},
  character::complete::none_of,
  combinator::recognize,
  multi::{many0, separated_list0},
  sequence::delimited,
  IResult,
};

fn parse_quoted_1(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  delimited(
    tag("'"),
    alt((escaped(none_of("\\\'"), '\\', tag("'")), tag(""))),
    tag("'"),
  )(input)
}

fn parse_quoted_2(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  delimited(
    tag("'"),
    recognize(separated_list0(tag("\\'"), many0(none_of("'")))),
    tag("'"),
  )(input)
}

fn main() {
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_1(r#"'1'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_2(r#"'1'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_1(r#"'1 \' 2'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_2(r#"'1 \' 2'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_1(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_2(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_1(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3 \\ 4'"#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted_2(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3 \\ 4'"#));
}

/*
Ok(("", "1"))
Ok(("", "1"))
Ok(("", "1 \\' 2"))
Ok((" 2'", "1 \\"))
Err(Error(Error { input: "1 \\' 2 \\ 3'", code: Tag }))
Ok((" 2 \\ 3'", "1 \\"))
Err(Error(Error { input: "1 \\' 2 \\ 3 \\\\ 4'", code: Tag }))
Ok((" 2 \\ 3 \\\\ 4'", "1 \\"))
*/
```

Only first 3 cases work as intended.

Comment: Please provide the expected output for each println

Comment: > I want to parse strings like `'1 \' 2 \ 3 \\ 4'` (a raw sequence of characters) as `"1 \\' 2 \\ 3 \\\\ 4"` (a Rust string)

Comment: I think I can do it by just manually looping over input, etc., but maybe there is a nice combinatorial way.

Comment: You can just do ```string.replace(r#"\"#, r#"\\"#);```

Comment: I'm parsing a few GB file, such strings are just one case in its syntax, so since `input` is few GB I can't pre-`replace` on it, and it isn't faithful w.r.t. other syntax anyway.

Comment: Oh, and `r#"\"#` is `"\\"` already, not `r#"\\"#` (that is `"\\\\"`), so the output is the input, just without the outermost `'` (but with inner `\'`).

Answer (score 0):

A non-nice/imperative solution:

```rust
use nom::{bytes::complete::take, character::complete::char, sequence::delimited, IResult};

fn parse_quoted(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  fn escaped(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let mut pc = 0 as char;
    let mut n = 0;
    for (i, c) in input.chars().enumerate() {
      if c == '\'' && pc != '\\' {
        break;
      }
      pc = c;
      n = i + 1;
    }
    take(n)(input)
  }
  delimited(char('\''), escaped, char('\''))(input)
}

fn main() {
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted(r#"'' ..."#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted(r#"'1' ..."#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted(r#"'1 \' 2' ..."#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3' ..."#));
  println!("{:?}", parse_quoted(r#"'1 \' 2 \ 3 \\ 4' ..."#));
}

/*
Ok((" ...", ""))
Ok((" ...", "1"))
Ok((" ...", "1 \\' 2"))
Ok((" ...", "1 \\' 2 \\ 3"))
Ok((" ...", "1 \\' 2 \\ 3 \\\\ 4"))
*/
```

To allow for `'...\\'` we can similarly store more previous characters:

```rust
    let mut pc = 0 as char;
    let mut ppc = 0 as char;
    let mut pppc = 0 as char;
    let mut n = 0;
    for (i, c) in input.chars().enumerate() {
      if (c == '\'' && pc != '\\') || (c == '\'' && pc == '\\' && ppc == '\\' && pppc != '\\') {
        break;
      }
      pppc = ppc;
      ppc = pc;
      pc = c;
      n = i + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to parse quoted string.

It returns `Cow` type with reference to original string when there is not strings that require escaping or copy of the string without escaping slashes.

You might need to adjust `is_gdtext` and `is_quited_char` to your needs.

```rust
// is valid character that do not require escaping
fn is_qdtext(chr: char) -> bool {
    match chr {
        '\t' => true,
        ' ' => true,
        '!' => true,
        '#'..='[' => true,
        ']'..='~' => true,
        _ => {
            let x = chr as u8;
            x >= 0x80
        }
    }
}

// check if character can be escaped
fn is_quoted_char(chr: char) -> bool {
    match chr {
        ' '..='~' => true,
        '\t' => true,
        _ => {
            let x = chr as u8;
            x >= 0x80
        }
    }
}

/// parse single escaped character
fn parse_quoted_pair(data: &str) -> IResult<&str, char> {
    let (data, (_, chr)) = pair(tag("\\"), satisfy(is_quoted_char))(data)?;
    Ok((data, chr))
}

// parse content of quoted string
fn parse_quoted_content(data: &str) -> IResult<&str, Cow<'_, str>> {
    let (mut data, content) = data.split_at_position_complete(|item| !is_qdtext(item))?;

    if data.chars().next() == Some('\\') {
        // we need to escape some characters
        let mut content = content.to_string();
        while data.chars().next() == Some('\\') {
            // unescape next char
            let (next_data, chr) = parse_quoted_pair(data)?;
            content.push(chr);
            data = next_data;

            // parse next plain text chunk
            let (next_data, extra_content) =
                data.split_at_position_complete(|item| !is_qdtext(item))?;
            content.push_str(extra_content);
            data = next_data;
        }
        Ok((data, Cow::Owned(content)))
    } else {
        // quick version, there is no characters to escape
        Ok((data, Cow::Borrowed(content)))
    }
}

fn parse_quoted_string(data: &str) -> IResult<&str, Cow<'_, str>> {
    let (data, (_, content, _)) = tuple((tag("'"), parse_quoted_content, tag("'")))(data)?;

    Ok((data, content))
}
```